# How to Put Routerlink in IconButton in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router, react-router-dom

How can i put the routerlink in reactjs button?

I tried these two below: the first one changes the color while the second one, i don't like it since it is reloading the page.

**FIRST**

```
<Link to="/settings">
    <IconButton color="inherit">
        <SettingsIcon />
    </IconButton>
</Link>
```

**SECOND**

```
<IconButton color="inherit" href="/settings">
    <SettingsIcon />
 </IconButton>
```

Comment: Don't you like use `useHistory` for pushing new route?

Comment: Can you show it?

Comment: Add `onClick` to `IconButton` and in callback function: `history.push('/settings')`

Comment: @BeHappy. Thanks. thats another package again hehe.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. :(

Comment: @BeHappy. I mean i have to do install again another package called history? https://www.npmjs.com/package/history

Comment: No, I add code in answer. check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Component() {
    const history = useHistory();

    return (
        <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={() => history.push("/setting")}>
            <SettingsIcon />
        </IconButton>
    );
}
```

Comment: If you do this then the button won't behave like a link. For example it will not show link target on mouse hover, "copy URL" might not work and middle click might not open the link in a new tab/window.

Answer (score 34):

@BeHappy's solution is good, but you can implement this using composition. No need to use hook.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings';

export default function Component() {
  return (
    <IconButton component={Link} to="/setting">
      <SettingsIcon />
    </IconButton>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried that and got and error on Typescript :-( (No overload matches this call.)    <IconButton component={Link} to="/about" variant="contained" color="primary">
  About Page
</IconButton>

Comment: Setting `component` attribute to `Link` seems to work technically but breaks the style of the button. The button got misaligned and the grey circle indicating hover disappeared after I used this method.

Comment: Make sure you import `Link` from `react-router-dom` and not from `@mui/material/Link` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to inject a `Link` into `IconButton` as follows. This approach preserves material-ui classes and CSS styling by capturing them in a `span` that wraps the `Link` component. The same `span` is also used to store the forward reference `ref`. I'm not sure why exactly it is needed but leaving it out seemed to be generate warnings.

```js
import React from "react";
import { IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings';

export default function Component() {
  return (
    <IconButton component={React.forwardRef(
      ({children, ...props}, ref) => (
        <span {...props} ref={ref}><Link>{children}</Link></span>
      )
    )}>
      <SettingsIcon />
    </IconButton>
  )
}
```